# How to find specific Kubernetes resource and "terminate/finalize" it when namespace deletion is stuck?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Hi I tried to delete some namespaces and they are stuck in terminating...

From the below details, I tried to delete the supposed rolebindings and roles, but they won't delete either and I don't know where to find the resources for: wrangler.cattle.io/auth-prov-v2-rb and wrangler.cattle.io/auth-prov-v2-role

```
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-08-09T21:30:18Z"
    message: All resources successfully discovered
    reason: ResourcesDiscovered
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceDeletionDiscoveryFailure
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-08-09T21:30:18Z"
    message: All legacy kube types successfully parsed
    reason: ParsedGroupVersions
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceDeletionGroupVersionParsingFailure
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-08-09T21:30:18Z"
    message: All content successfully deleted, may be waiting on finalization
    reason: ContentDeleted
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceDeletionContentFailure
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-08-09T21:30:18Z"
    message: 'Some resources are remaining: rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      has 2 resource instances, roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io has 1 resource instances'
    reason: SomeResourcesRemain
    status: "True"
    type: NamespaceContentRemaining
  - lastTransitionTime: "2023-08-09T21:30:18Z"
    message: 'Some content in the namespace has finalizers remaining: wrangler.cattle.io/auth-prov-v2-rb
      in 2 resource instances, wrangler.cattle.io/auth-prov-v2-role in 1 resource
      instances'
    reason: SomeFinalizersRemain
    status: "True"
    type: NamespaceFinalizersRemaining
```

Answer (score 2):

There was a bunch of resources: roles, role bindings (+cluster) and custom resources that all had finalizers, that wouldn't delete either. So I patched all those resources by removing the finalizer and everything started to finally delete itself.